# Can you trigger a modern EHX Super Space Drum / Crash Pad by stomping on it?

Tags: effects-pedal

Just wondering if anyone owns a modern Electro Harmonix Super Space Drum or Crash Pad, and if you can reliably trigger it by stepping on it. I can't find any videos of anyone doing this and I can't tell if that tiny white button would be triggered by stomping on it.

Comment: Are you afraid to crash it (pun intended) or that it won't trigger?

Comment: afraid it won't trigger

Comment: @Tom see my comment above